# Can I host COM+ application in WCF?

Tags: wcf, com+

Is it possible to host my COM Objects in WCF?  I want to move them out of the Component service.  Any advise will help

Answer (score 1):

No - WCF is not a hosting environment for services - it's a communication framework that itself needs to be hosted - in IIS / WAS or self-hosted in any managed app.

WCF can interface with COM+ - but it's not a hosting provider that can host COM+